# Define $f(x)=0$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}^c$; $f(x)=p-q$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ where $x=\frac{p}{q}$ in lowest terms

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-sum

Define $f(x)=0$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}^c$; $f(x)=p-q$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ where $x=\frac{p}{q}$ in lowest terms (conventional way to represent rationals). The question asks that whether f is Riemann integrable on [0,1]. I think this is kind of similar to the popcorn function but have no idea how to (dis)prove it...

Comment: Hint: let $a$ be irrational and let $p_n/q_n$ converge to $a$. Is it possible that $f(p_n/q_n)=p_n-q_n$ converges to $f(a)=0$? What can you conclude from this?

Comment: That f is not continuous at $x\in  \mathbb{Q}^c$ so not Riemann integrable?